# The status / acceptance of block time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, soft-question, spacetime, time

What is the current status or acceptance of [block time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_%28philosophy_of_time%29) as it relates to Einstein's theory of relativity? Has quantum mechanics ruled it out or is it still the favored view of the world? Perhaps there can't be any consensus as we cannot link quantum mechanics with relativity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a particle's position be random and uncertain in quantum mechanics if it is already pre-determined in relatvity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426583/)

Answer (score 4):

Block time is not a physical theory. It's a philosophical interpretation. It can't be tested empirically. For these reasons it doesn't really make sense to ask for its status or whether it's accepted. You can poll physicists on whether they like it (there have been polls like this, for example, on the Copenhagen interpretation versus many-worlds), but the results are pretty meaningless. I could vote one way in the poll one day and then vote the opposite way the next day. There would be no contradiction, because the choice of interpretation has no effect on any prediction that can be compared with the results of actual experiments.