# Block universe and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism

Can a [block universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time)) (complete determinism) ever be compatible with quantum mechanics?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a particle's position be random and uncertain in quantum mechanics if it is already pre-determined in relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426583)

Comment: I think the answer to this question will depend greatly on what interpretation of QM you find most convincing. The Everett interpretation is deterministic.